# Compiling a JasperReports template programatically and/or with Ant

Tags: java, ant, jasper-reports

So I've done a lot of fruitless Googling/and Stack-exploring over the past week or so and still can't get my first .jrxml filled with data and converted into a .pdf... I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out with a significant amount of hand-holding.

- First, I used JasperSoft 6.3 to design the template. Unfortunately it doesn't have compile functionality.
- Compiling my .jrxml with Ant + Ivy gives me 3 errors all relating to an obscure directory called **mondrian**, specifically:

  ```
  tuples[idx] = new JRMondrianTuple(position, factory);
  class file for Position not found
  hierarchies[i] = new JRMondrianHierarchy(axisHierarchies[i]);
  class file for Hierarchy not found
  mondrianMember = new JRMondrianMember(member, this);
  class file for Member not found
  ```

  Each of which is preceded by something like:

  ```
  C:\jasperreports-6.3.0\src\net\sf\jasperreports\olap\mondrian\JR...java:...:
  ```

  The build file is:

  ```
  <project name="aaa" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property name="sample.dir" value="aaa"/>
    <property name="sample.base.name" value="aaa"/>
    <property name="sample.app.name" value="${sample.base.name}App"/>
    <property name="sample.report.name" value="reportDesign.jrxml" />
    <target name="javac">
      <ant dir="../" target="javac"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
      <ant dir="../" target="compile"/>
    </target>
    <target name="test" >
      <echo message="==================================="/>
      <antcall target="javac" />
      <antcall target="compile" />
      <ant dir="../" target="test"/>
    </target>
  </project>
  ```
- Meanwhile, compiling programmatically using the following:

  ```
  try {
      JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(".reportDesign.jrxml","compiledReport.jasper");
      System.out.println("Done!");
  } catch (JRException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Gives me errors (NoClassDefFoundError) which adding external JARs should have fixed but didn't.

```
Filling report...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.<init>(ComponentsEnvironment.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getInstance(ComponentsEnvironment.java:76)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:93)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1580)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1549)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:253)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:554)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: `which adding external JARs should have fixed but didn't.` - What list of libs in cp do you have?

Comment: You shall add `commons-beanutils`, `commons-collections`, `commons-digester`, `commons-javaflow`, `commons-logging` to classpath.

Comment: beansutil, collections, digester, logging, itext, jasperreports-6.3.0, jdt-compiler